# How to redirect subfolders in Ionic/website

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, browser, web-development-server

I currently have a ionic webapp that is hosted as x url (e.g. www.myApp.com). My app has subfolders e.g. myApp.com/home or myApp.com/details. Unfortunately, whenever I refresh any of these subfolders, I get an error like 'Cannot GET /home' (only the base URL/Domain works).

If possible, is there any way to either host these sub-folders on Google Domains (so GD would automatically redirect these links back to the baes myApp.com link if they're refreshed) or do I need to do something within the code itself to accomplish this?

EDIT: I understand now that I have to re-route using my web server so that I can return the index.html when a user refreshes the page on a false link e.g. (ionicSite.com/Page). For reference, I've included my server.js file below:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var cors = require('cors');

// Server Redirection changes
const targetURL = "www.ambitia.org";
const path = require ('path');

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
// app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('www'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.get('/home', (req,res) => {
  console.log('You asked for my home!');
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('/main-es2015.js'));
})

/**
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  ('Attempting the redirection goal');
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname));
}) **/

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "my app has subfolders"? Is this /home or /details routes from the Angular/Ionic application? Or a real "subfolder" in the server?

Comment: Apologies, should've clarified. As you said, it's basically just routes e.g. /home or /details from the Ionic app itself. It's just that when I refresh e.g. /home, it causes the error (as the domain only points to the base url only)

Comment: For clarity, I think this issue summarises my own better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117884/cannot-get-error-after-refresh-using-ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to tell your server that it should redirect the requests to your `index.html` so that Ionic can handle the routing.

On Apache you can add a `.htaccess` file in the root folder with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Source: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I'm struggling with this part unfortuantely. I've tried several times to force my server.js file (node/expressJS) to re-route to index.html but it usually returns a NOT FOUND error. I've edited my main question to include the server.js code. Do you know how to re-route?